# How built-in functions like 'quantile' are implemented in R?

Tags: r, built-in

Is there a way we can check or see the definition/body of these functions, or how these are implemented?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)

Comment: In addition, `quantile` has a manual page that provides descriptions of the 9 types of quantiles that it computes.

Comment: @mischva11 

I think I got my answer, and that it's above my skills.